# ArchUnit - How to find if a field is a spring bean or not

Tags: archunit

I have to place this special architecture-rule in my project where classes that are annotated with `@RestController` or `@Service` or `@Component` should include instance variables that are **only Spring beans**.

For example Let's take this class

```java
@Service
public class HotelsService {

 
    private Map<String, String> availableAreasHotelMap;

    @Autowired
    private HotelsDao hotelsDao;

    public List<Hotel> fetchAllHotels() {
        return dummyHotelsList();
    }
}
```

The above should make my arch-unit test fail, because I haven't declared any bean for `availableAreasHotelMap`.

Whereas if i include a bean this way

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean("availableAreasHotelMap")
    public Map<String, String> availableAreasHotelMap () {
        return Map.of("india","hote-1","chicago","hotel-2");
    }
}
```

my arch-unit test case should pass, after detecting a bean declaration. Not sure how to do this in arch-unit. Even for spring, it would be able to detect only during run-time, but how to do this during compile-time ?? is this impossible at all ??

Answer (score 0):

### Checking annotations of field types

It's a complex process to figure out whether a field or an object is a Spring bean or not. This is mainly due to the fact that beans can be defined very flexibly.

The simplest use case would be to check that field types have a related annotation:

```java
fields()
    .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(RestController.class)
    .should().haveRawType(annotatedWith(Component.class));
```

This example should find cases like

```java
@RestController
class MyRestController {

    @Autowired
    MyService service;
}

@Component
class MyService {
}
```

As you have already noticed, this fails already with `@Bean` methods.

```java
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MyService myService() {
        return new MyService();
    }
}
```

In this case, we would therefore have to check whether there are any suitable `@Bean` methods.

But what if the `@Bean` method returns a `FactoryBean<MyService>` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html)) to create the object at a later point in time? Or what if we don't inject the MyService directly but as `ObjectProvider<MyService> myServiceProvider` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html))? Or maybe we want to inject all instances of a given type as `List<MyService> myServices`?

The next thing we need to consider are *meta-annotations* and *composed annotations*. For example, every class annotated with `@RestController` is also meta-annotated with `@Component`. ([Spring Annotation Programming Model](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model))

### Checking component structure

I would probably focus more on how the individual components are structured, and then test that structure with ArchUnit. Probably the architectural goal could be that controllers and services are stateless. In this case, a suitable structure would be that all fields are final.

```java
@RestController
class MyRestController {

    private final MyService service;

    MyRestController(MyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Spring can then create instances only if all constructor parameters are known as Spring bean.

The ArchUnit rule could be:

```java
fields()
    .that().areDeclaredInClassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(RestController.class)
    .should().beFinal();
```

That would still leave the possibility for developers to create additional fields like `private final Object mutex = new Object();` or so. But the effort for checking with ArchUnit is reduced.

See also [Why field injection is evil](http://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) and the existing [ArchUnit rule to prevent field injection](https://javadoc.io/static/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/1.0.1/com/tngtech/archunit/library/GeneralCodingRules.html#NO_CLASSES_SHOULD_USE_FIELD_INJECTION).

I hope this gives you new ideas to solve the problem.

Comment: As shown in my post, we can even create a Map and mark it as bean and autowire that map in any components .. How can archunit know that the field, which is map is a bean (only in runtime or through application context, this can be figured out)

Comment: As I said, because it's very complicated to figure this out outside of Spring, I would rather test/enforce constructor injection via ArchUnit. If that is implemented, Spring can only create the objects if it has beans for it.